# Scala, list the existing files in URL

Tags: scala, url

I want to list all files in :
http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html

Is there any way/lib to do that? if NOT is there any way to check if a random file exist without attempting to download it? (so I can generate all possible downloadable files in the URL)

Answer (score 1):

Scala doesn't have anything specific for that, you have to use some library to parse HTML page and extract URLs.

[Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) is a good candidate. [This is](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) an example about using CSS selectors to find elements.

Comment: As a note, when using Jsoup with Scala, you'll probably want to make use of `JavaConverters` or `JavaConversions` to use the usual `map`, `filter`, etc. methods that you'd expect on a list of nodes.